# Как убрать толстую строку в PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

При начале использовании программы и при выделение кода вместо обычной строки появляеться толстая белая строчка, которую никак кроме нажатия буквы S не убрать. Также с ней невозможно вписать хоть что-то в код, и исправить что-то там. Проблема в программе PyCharm на macOS.

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwlUD.png строка до выделения

[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHLKh.png строка после выделения

Comment: У вас клавиатура переведена в режим замены (клавиша ins)

Comment: А какая клавиша на macbook отвечает за это?

Comment: Скачал эмулятор, заменил клавишу fn на insert, но ничего не поменялось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Как указывали выше File > Settings > Editor > General > Appearance убрать галочку 'Use block caret'
2. Отключить плагин [IdeaVim](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/enabling-and-disabling-plugins.html)

Comment: Спасибо, отключить IdeavVim правда помогло.

Comment: @Арсений, а Вы, случайно, не помните как так случилось, что у Вас появился плагин IdeaVim?

Comment: Кажется он был в изначальной папке. Я не скачивал никаких плагинов.

Answer (score 0):

Наверно Вы имеете ввиду тип курсора? 
Чтобы можно было выделять, без всяких изменений зайдите в `Preferences=>Editor=>Appearance` проставить или убрать параметр `Use block caret`
После этого файл будет как в обычном редакторе.

Comment: Увы, ничего не поменялось. Но в любом случае спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

В моем случае
Как указывали выше File > Settings > Editor > General > Appearance убрать галочку 'Use block caret' - **галочка была убрана**

Отключение  плагина IdeaVim помогло решить проблему